# Get cell by column name using xlrd

Tags: python, xlrd

If I have two rows in an Excel (.xls) sheet, like a key-value pair, is there a way to get the value (row1) by entering in the key (row0) in xlrd?

For example, if I have `(0,0) = COLOR` and `(1,0) = RED`, how would I do something like:

```
value = sh.col_values("COLOR") ?
```

The closest I have been able to find is `sh.col_values(int)`, but that only allows me to enter in an index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to search down the column until you find `COLOR` then get the value in the next row.

```
from itertools import product

def value_from_key(sheet, key):
    for row_index, col_index in product(xrange(sheet.nrows), xrange(sheet.ncols)):
        if sheet.cell(row_index, col_index).value == key:
            return sheet.cell(row_index+1, col_index).value

value = value_from_key(sheet, 'COLOR')
```

If you knew the keys were in even or odd rows you could use `xrange(0, sheet.nrows, 2)` or `xrange(1, sheet.nrows, 2)` instead.

Edit: Updated to search columns as well.

Comment: Check out my edit. That should search the whole sheet for the key, then return the value of the cell immediately below. If you can further restrict the search space just change the `xrange`s.

Comment: @agf, that is awesome.  My program only needs to search the columns in row 0, but a bit of modification from the first version of your answer worked perfectly.  The only trick was in the sheet.cell(row_index, column) line.  I tried replacing the parameters with (column_index, row).  But obviously that was the wrong order.

Comment: `AttributeError: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'nrows'`

Comment: @Cerin This definitely worked when posted, and `nrows` and `ncols` still show up in the README for xlrd so no reason to think that's changed: https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd -- care to show your code?